# Blender mirror not symmetrical

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

[image]
[image]

First image is before mirror, and the second is after.

As you can see the most left vertices are perfectily aligned on Z axis

But when I hit apply for Mirror modifier, actually they turn out they are not symmetrical.

For example, the distance between the vertices in red circles and the black area has to be equal.

But as you can see in the second image, the left ones are further away than the right ones.

The top right circled vertex perfectly aligns with the border between black & blue object,

whilst the left mirrored does not clearly.

***Things Ive tried to fix this:***

1. I chekced the numerical data of position, and they actually match each other \

   - e.g) the aforementioned vertex that "aligns with the border between black & blue object" has position of 0.8 X, 0.7 Y, -0.3 Z values, and the mirrored one on the right, that is broken, has a position of -0.8 X, 0.7 Y, -0.3 Z. They match each other and so do all other vertices
2. Applying all transform
3. recalculating normals though I have no idea what that means

Why is this happening????

Comment: I had a problem understanding the issue, so here's a GIF that shows more clearly the asymmetry: https://imgur.com/5DfZfVx - the geometry is symmetrical, but not shading. Consider uploading the file to https://blend-exchange.com/ for a higher chance of getting help.